# Echo PHP array to Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, google-visualization

I'm currently working on a project where I need to get data from a DB and produce it as a Javascript array. Its to dynamically change a graph.

I have the following PHP code to get an array.

```
<?php
  ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M');
  $dbconn = pg_connect(**My connection details**)
          or die('Could not connect: ' . pg_last_error());

  $county1 = $_GET['c1'];
  $county2 = $_GET['c2'];
  $county3 = "National";

  $counties = 'SELECT * FROM house_price_data_db.county_median_months where county=$1 or county=$2 or county=$3 order by county';
  $result_counties = pg_query_params($dbconn,$counties,array($county1,$county2,$county3)) or die('Query failed: ' . pg_last_error());
   $county_meds = array();

   while($r = pg_fetch_assoc($result_counties)) {
          $county_meds[] = $r;
      }
   echo("var county_med_month=".json_encode(array_values($county_meds), JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK).";");

   pg_free_result($result_counties);
   pg_close($dbconn);
?>
```

Which when run does indeed return the array.

```
E.g
var county_med_month=[
{"county":"Carlow","med_jan_10":165000,"med_feb_10":170000,...,"med_dec_14":null}
{"county":"Dublin","med_jan_10":285000,"med_feb_10":280000,...,"med_dec_14":null},
{"county":"National","med_jan_10":220264.31,"med_feb_10":216500,...,"med_dec_14":null}];
```

But for some reasons when I try to use the array in the Javascript code it doesn't seem to work?

```
function county_med_chart(){
  county_1=document.getElementById("dd1_c").value;
  county_2=document.getElementById("dd2_c").value;
  var c;
  county_meds(county_1,county_2);
  for(c=0;c<county_med_month.length;c+=1){
    var a=county_med_month.c;
    if(a.county==county_1){
      med_jan_10_1=parseFloat(a.med_jan_10);
       :
      med_sep_14_1=parseFloat(a.med_sep_14);
    }
    else if(a.county==county_2){
      med_jan_10_2=parseFloat(a.med_jan_10);    
       :
      med_sep_14_2=parseFloat(a.med_sep_14);
    }
    else if(a.county=="National"){
      med_jan_10_3=parseFloat(a.med_jan_10);
       :
      med_sep_14_3=parseFloat(a.med_sep_14);
    }
  }

  var e=new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ["Year",county_1,county_2,"National"],
    ["Jan-10",med_jan_10_1,med_jan_10_2,med_jan_10_3],
    ["Feb-10",med_feb_10_1,med_feb_10_2,med_feb_10_3],
     :
    ["Aug-14",med_aug_14_1,med_aug_14_2,med_aug_14_3],
    ["Sept-14",med_sep_14_1,med_sep_14_2,med_sep_14_3],
  ]);

  var b={
    title:"House Price Index by County:",
    curveType:"function",
    is3D:true,
    legend:"top",
    width:650,
    height:280,
    hAxis: { textPosition: 'none' }};
  var d=new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById("chart_div"));
  d.draw(e,b)
  }
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you try changing `var a=county_med_month.c;` for `var a=county_med_month[c];`?

Comment: Did you try to console.log your county_med_month variable after setting it from PHP? This would rule out any json parsing errors.

Comment: @Naomi: I've tried both forms and seem to still run into problems.
ToBe: Can you link me to or provide any further explanation, as I don't quite get what you mean.

Comment: Are you able to have some console output for `county_med_month`? What error do you get? I think you are not creating the array in javascript in the first place. Try doing something like this in your javascript `var foo = <?php echo json_encode($county_meds ); ?>;`

Comment: Em I've tried checking the console on running the PHP script from the function using Firebug, and I tried putting in an alert if the array length was greater than 0, but not getting anywhere.
Is there something wrong with trying to use the array as created above?
    
     echo("var county_med_month=".json_encode(array_values($county_meds), JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK).";");

Comment: @ToBe: I've tried that, and when I run I get the following error:
ReferenceError: county_med_month is not defined

Answer (score 0):

Try this way to catch your `json` encoded data,

```
var a=county_med_month[c].county;
```

For more info. about json array and object access :[JSON](https://www.json.com/)

Comment: alert(county_med_month[c].country);

Comment: Em do you mean use 
     county_med_month[c].county; 
As I'm trying to set a equal to 1 entry/row in the array, as in county, med_jan_10, med_feb_10 etc.. not just to the value of county.

Comment: Then assign the whole json object(single row as you say) like var a=country_med_month[c] where c=0,1,2,3......but if you want to access or assign individual keys of individual row, then you have to set like this var a=country_med_month[c].country

Comment: Ok that's fine, I'll try that. I just wanted to know if you meant country or county, as that had me confused also?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try debugging your code before doing any complicated logic with it?

Just after echoing your array try the following at the top of your javascript:

```
if(county_med_month.length > 0) 
    console.log("The array was created!, the problem was with my JavaScript code!");
```

And by the way you don't access an array value with dot notation

```
var a=county_med_month.c;
```

Should have red

```
var a=county_med_month[c];
```